# How can I remove blown-out sun glare reflected from a sign?

Tags: post-processing, gimp, glare

I've been asked to fix up the banner in this photo to remove the glare. I've played around with some of the answers I've found on the internet already, but haven't had any luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I'm using GIMP.

[image: Car outside of a tyre shop the sun is on the name of the shop making two letters not appear]

Answer (score 5):

In the glare the image is totally burned out (all three channels maxed out),
so you best bet is to reconstruct the letters (which, fortunately for you, are mostly straight lines).

I would do this (Gimp or PS) by creating a path that outlines the missing bits and overlaps the remaining ones, getting a selection from that, and apply a gradient:

[image]

- The blue line is a path that marks the base line of the letters, useful to tell where the foot of the `N`and `T` are.4
- The red line is the path that makes the outline of the letters
- The white line with `+` at the ends marks the gradient

This is a quick hack, but if you draw the gradient on separate layer, you can play with local opacity to make it blend a bit more naturally in the original image.

[image]

Alternatively you add the `U`and the other `T` in the processing to remove the glare on them.

Edit: for a slightly cleaner and more natural looking result:

Insert a layer and clone a non-glare area to fill the overexposed glare area:

[image]

Comment: If you go this route, and you should, you might as well remove the shadows cast by the lights.

Comment: @Steve I disagree. If you did that, you ought to just remove the lights. Because there are other sun-direction and shade clues in the image. Having the lights not cast a shadow causes a slight uncanny-valley effect, that removal of specular glare doesn't, IMO.

Comment: @scottbb That's actually a good point!

Comment: Thanks @Xenoid I thought that might be the case but figured I'd ask nonetheless :)